# Change default category in phmyadmin after update products in prestashop

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, prestashop

I have a simple issue. 
For a real programmer it schould be peanuts..

I want to change the category of a product when is this product is affected by a specific price rule.

this is what I have, but nothing happens ...

```js
UPDATE psc5_product AND psc5_product_shop SET id_category_default=771 WHERE id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM psc5_specific_price WHERE id_specific_price>0);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE `psc5_product`
SET `id_category_default` = 771
WHERE `id_product` IN (SELECT `id_product` FROM `psc5_specific_price` GROUP BY `id_product`);

UPDATE `psc5_product_shop`
SET `id_category_default` = 771
WHERE `id_product` IN (SELECT `id_product` FROM `psc5_specific_price` GROUP BY `id_product`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is a little more complicated as I thought.

When a preset specific price rule is starting (from - to - date) this is no update happening in the table psc5_product. So the trigger is not starting his work.

So I need mysql script that starts to work on the from date untill the end date, when the end date is over the change need to be turned back.

Example:

rule 1:
id_product 1 id_category_default 1 price rule from to 09-09-2018 00:00:00 to 10-09-2018 23:59:59 ---> needs to get a change to id_category_default 2

rule 2:
On 11-09-2018 00:00:00 id_product is no longer affected by the price rule and the id_category_default needs to get 1 again.

For the moment I don't have a clue how to start this... 
The hard part for me, is the fact that the the category id in rule 2 (after the end of the promotion) is variable (I have 771 categories...) in rule 1 this is fixed, no so hard...

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
//Deleting old products in this category
Db::getInstance()->executes('DELETE FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product WHERE id_category = 771');

//Recovery of products with a reduction
$req = Db::getInstance()->executes('SELECT id_product FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'specific_price');

//Product update with the correct default category + Product attribution in the category
foreach ($req as $resu) {
    $prod = new Product($resu['id_product']);
    $prod->id_category_default = 771;
    $prod->save();
    $product->addToCategories(array(0 => 771));
}
```